# Is there a way to to make this personality quiz in object oriented programming?

Tags: python, object-oriented-analysis

so far i've tried creating QBank class that will print and calculate the percentages of all the categories, and PType class that will output the personality type. this is the non object oriented code:

```
apercent = {}
apercent["A"] = 0
apercent["B"] = 0
apercent["C"] = 0
apercent["D"] = 0
questions = [
    {"q": "Would you call yourself a thinker", "f": "D"},
    {"q": "Are you creative", "f": "D"},
    {"q": "Do you like philosophy", "f": "D"},
    {"q": "Do you like to think about complex questions", "f": "D"},
    {"q": "Do you have an interest in artisitc pursuits like painting and writing", "f": "D"},
    {"q": "Do you like initiating conversations", "f": "A"},
    {"q": "Do you like to start talks with new people", "f": "A"},
    {"q": "Is it easy for you to adjust in an enviroment where you initially do not know anyone", "f": "A"},
    {"q": "Are you social", "f": "A"},
    {"q": "Do you like social events (parties, fests and events)", "f": "A"},
    {"q": "Do you mostly make your decisions by heart", "f": "B"},
    {"q": "Do you put others before yourself", "f": "B"},
    {"q": "Do you think that one should change their views if they hurt someone", "f": "B"},
    {"q": "Do you often get lost in your feelings", "f": "B"},
    {"q": "Are you run more by your feelings than logic", "f": "B"},
    {"q": "Can you make a timetable and stick to it", "f": "C"},
    {"q": "Do you usually follow the rules/laws", "f": "C"},
    {"q": "Are you organised", "f": "C"},
    {"q": "Do you plan before doing something", "f": "C"},
    {"q": "Are you ok with following orders", "f": "C"}
]
def question(index, inp, func):
    if bool(input(str(index + 1) + ". " + inp + "? Yes/No:\t").lower().strip("no. \t")):
        apercent[func] = apercent[func] + 20
try:
     for q in range(len(questions)):
          question(q, questions[q]["q"], questions[q]["f"])
except KeyboardInterrupt:
     exit(0)
print("Your extroversion percentage : ", apercent["A"], "%")
print("Your creativity percentage : ", apercent["N"], "%")
print("Your feeling percentage : ", apercent["B"], "%")
print("Your conscientious percentage : ", apercent["C"], "%")
if apercent["N"] > 50:
    sn = "N"
else:
    sn = "S"
if apercent["A"] > 50:
    ie = "E"
else:
    ie = "I"

if apercent["C"] > 50:
    jp = "J"
else:
    jp = "P"

if apercent["B"] > 50:
    tf = "F"
else:
    tf = "T"
ptype = ie + sn + tf + jp
print("Your personality type is: ", ptype)
```

this is how i tried to make QBank object oriented:

```
class QBank:

  def _init_(self, questions, percentage):
    self.questions = questions
    self.percentage = percentage


  def printQuestions(self, q):
    q = ["Would you call yourself a thinker (Y/N):",
    "Are you creative (Y/N):",
    "Do you like philosophy (Y/N):",
    "Do you like to think about complex questions (Y/N):",
    "Do you have an interest in artisitc pursuits like painting and writing (Y/N):",
    "Do you like initiating conversations (Y/N):",
    "Do you like to start talks with new people (Y/N):",
    "Is it easy for you to adjust in an enviroment where you initially do not know anyone (Y/N):",
    "Are you social (Y/N):",
    "Do you like social events (parties, fests and events) (Y/N):",
    "Do you mostly make your decisions by heart (Y/N):",
    "Do you put others before yourself (Y/N):",
    "Do you think that one should change their views if they hurt someone (Y/N):",
    "Do you often get lost in your feelings (Y/N):",
    "Are you run more by your feelings than logic (Y/N):",
    "Can you make a timetable and stick to it (Y/N):",
    "Do you usually follow the rules/laws (Y/N):",
    "Are you organised (Y/N):",
    "Do you plan before doing something (Y/N):",
    "Are you ok with following orders (Y/N):"]

    f= ["D","D","D","D","D","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C",]

    z = list(zip(q,f))

    for x in range (len(q)):
      print(q, input(" "))

print(QBank.printQuestions(q))
```

and this is for PType

```
class PType:
    def __init__(self, personality, anime, movie, career):
        self.personality  = personality
        self.anime = anime
        self.movie = movie
        self.career = career

    def printValues(self):
        print("Your personality type is: ", self.personality)
        print("Anime character: ", self.anime)
        print("Tv show/movie character: ", self.movie)
        print("Career options: ", self.career)

    def calculatePtype(self):
        pass
        

p1 = PType("ENTJ", "Mikasa Ackerman", "Harrison Wells", "Businessman")

p1.printValues()
```

im just really stuck on how to do this in object oriented programming for python. especially for the calculations. can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3):

OOP is a different programming paradigm, i.e. a different way of thinking your code. So just putting more or less the same procedural code in a class definition will not make it OOP.

I took the liberty of fumbling a bit with your code, and I came up with four classes: Question, Personality Trait, Personality Type and finally a Quiz class which does nothing but create objects of the other classes and call their methods:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Question:
    text : str
    ptrait_code : str

    def ask(self):
        return (self.ptrait_code, input(f'{self.text}?: Yes/No')[0].upper() == "Y")


@dataclass
class PTrait:
    code : str
    title : str
    positive : str
    positive_desc : str
    negative : str
    negative_desc : str
    score : int = 0

    def show_score(self):
        if self.score > 50:
            print(f'Your {self.title} score is {self.score} so you could be described as {self.positive_desc}')
        else:
            print(f'Your {self.title} score is {self.score} so you could be described as {self.negative_desc}')

    def score2ptype(self):
        if self.score > 50:
            return self.positive
        return self.negative


@dataclass
class PType:
    code : str
    anime : str
    movie : str
    career : str
    
    def show_result(self):
        print(f'Your personality type is {self.code}')
        print(f'Your anime character is {self.anime}')
        print(f'Your movie is {self.movie}')
        print(f'Your career is {self.career}')


class Quiz:
    def __init__(self):
        self.questions = [Question("Would you call yourself a thinker","CRE"),
                          Question("Are you creative","CRE"),
                          Question("Do you like philosophy","CRE")
                          ]
        self.ptraits = {"EXT" : PTrait("EXT", "Extroversion", "E", "Extroverted", "I", "Introverted"),
                        "CRE" : PTrait("CRE", "Creativity", "N", "Creative", "S", "Down-to-earth")
                        }
        self.ptypes = {'ENTJ' : PType('ENTJ', "Mikasa Ackerman", "Harrison Wells", "Businessman")
                       }
        self.computed_ptype = ''

    def run_quiz(self):
        for q in self.questions:
            trait, answer = q.ask()
            if answer:
                self.ptraits[trait].score += 20
        print()
        for trait in self.ptraits:
            self.ptraits[trait].show_score()
            self.computed_ptype += self.ptraits[trait].score2ptype()
        print()
        ##force ENTJ since a few data are missing
        self.computed_ptype = "ENTJ"
        self.ptypes[self.computed_ptype].show_result()

q=Quiz()
q.run_quiz()
            
Would you call yourself a thinker?: Yes/No y
Are you creative?: Yes/No y
Do you like philosophy?: Yes/No y

Your Extroversion score is 0 so you could be described as Introverted
Your Creativity score is 60 so you could be described as Creative

Your personality type is ENTJ
Your anime character is Mikasa Ackerman
Your movie is Harrison Wells
Your career is Businessman
```

Comment: Thank you so much! just a q: @dataclass is just the short way for def __init__ func right?

Comment: Basically yes. Check the docs however, it is quite interesting

Comment: hello, so i tried running it after putting in the info, and whatever i input it shows 100 for all the categories in the output. also what do you put when you dont force ENTJ?

Comment: `def run_quiz(self):
        for q in self.questions:
            trait, answer = q.ask()
            if answer:
                self.ptraits[trait].score += 20
        print()
        for trait in self.ptraits:
            self.ptraits[trait].show_score()
            self.computed_ptype += self.ptraits[trait].score2ptype()
        print()
        #force ENTJ for now
        self.computed_ptype = "ENTJ"
        self.ptypes[self.computed_ptype].show_result()` this is the part i dont get

Comment: I am sorry, I copied something wrong. I'm editing the `input` line so that we get the correct boolean value. For the second question, just delete `self.computed_ptype = "ENTJ"`, the previous loop takes care of filling the variable

Comment: thank you so much, right now im still trying to understand everything you put and i might ask questions in the coming days i hope this is okay

Comment: Yes, of course.